# how to save multiple checkbox values in custom metabox in wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

Yes I know there is another related question which has been answered but I don't understand how to implement that solution in my code. I'm just a beginner, help me out. I want to save multiple checkbox values in custom metabox in a WordPress plugin. When user saves the post or updates it, the values of the checked checkboxes should be saved.

```
function cd_meta_box_cb($post){
global $post;
echo'<b> Select the contributors that have contributed to this post: </b>';
echo '<br><br>';   
wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
global $wpdb;
$authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users 
ORDER BY user_nicename");
$i=0;
$n=count($authors);
foreach($authors as $author) {
    echo"<input type='checkbox' id='my_meta_box_check' 
    name='my_meta_box_check'";
    echo"value=";
    the_author_meta('user_nicename', $author->ID);
    echo">";
    echo"<label for='author'.$i>";
    the_author_meta('user_nicename', $author->ID);
    echo"</label>";
    echo "<br />";
  }

 echo"<input type='submit' id='submit_btn' name='submit' value='Submit'>";
  }
//save custom data when our post is saved
 function save_custom_data($post_id) 
 {  
  global $post;
  $contributor=get_post_meta($post->ID,'my_meta_box_check',true);
  if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;     

 if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( 
 $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

// if our current user can't edit this post, bail
if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;
if ( isset($_POST['my_meta_box_check']) ) 
{        

    $data=serialize($_POST['my_meta_box_check']);   
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'my_meta_box_check',$data);      
 } 
else {
    delete_post_meta($post_id, 'my_meta_box_check');
 } 
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_custom_data' );
function displaymeta()
{

    global $post;
    $m_meta_description = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_meta_box_check', 
  true);
    echo 'Meta box value: ' . unserialize($m_meta_description);
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'displaymeta' );

?>
```

Comment: Hi komal 
what happen when you try to save meta values..

Comment: Hi Yogesh, when I save the post, it displays (because of filter) just one checkbox value on the post. Even if I check multiple values, it just displays one. And it stores just that one value in wppost_meta table as well. How can I store multiple meta values in one meta_key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mention checkbox field name as array like `my_meta_box_check[]`

Please use the code below

```
<input type='checkbox' id='my_meta_box_check' 
name='my_meta_box_check[]'" >
```

Please try this and check if it works for you.

Comment: Okay that solution stores the data in the database well, but when I try to echo it out, it says "Array". How do I display individual values of checked checkboxes?

Comment: Okay I used foreach loop and now it works perfectly fine! Thank you very much Yogesh! :) Cheers!

Comment: Hello, I have another query in another code, can you help me out? @Yogesh?

Comment: Hi @KomalR,
Ya sure. i will help you

Comment: Thanks a lot! Please check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51927113/how-to-display-admin-side-images-on-client-side-in-wordpress-programmatically

Comment: @KomalR, i checked this link, this task is easy but issue is that how can i send code to this. because this process is bit lengthy.

Comment: @KomalR you need to add functionality to upload images from back-end. and save these images in database. so that you can retrieve these images in front-end.

Comment: I have added the functionality to add the images to media library. And I can create a slideshow of images on admin page. But how do I display it on frontend?

Comment: Can you at least tell me the process of what I should do to achieve each step in that plugin? @Yogesh