# How to display admin side images on client side in WordPress programmatically?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am creating a WordPress plugin and I ask user to insert some images on the settings page of the plugin on admin side. Now when a `shortcode` is inserted in the post, **I want to display those images on the post**.

Actually, I am creating a **slideshow of these images**, so I want to display the slideshow. The slideshow is being previewed on the admin side and the same should be shown on the post when the `shortcode` is inserted.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#sortable').sortable();
      $(btn_refresh).click(function(){

        document.getElementById('is1').style.display="block";
        document.getElementById('is2').style.display="block";
        document.getElementById('is3').style.display="block";

        var itemOrder = $('#sortable').sortable("toArray")

        document.getElementById("is1").src=document.getElementById(itemOrder[0]).src;
        document.getElementById("is2").src=document.getElementById(itemOrder[1]).src;
        document.getElementById("is3").src=document.getElementById(itemOrder[2]).src

        w3.slideshow(".pics", 1100);
  });
</script>

<?php 
  function slideshow_fun(){

   }
   add_shortcode('slideshow_shortcode','slideshow_fun'); 
  ?>
```

Now what should I write in the PHP function to display the slideshow? By the way, `is1`, `is2`, `is3` are image tag ids that are previously defined on the same page. And this is a PHP file.

Comment: Your question is far too broad in current form. Admin and public facing pages are two distinct parts of WordPress. Loading libraries (i.e. `sortable()`) into each is done differently (you need to enqueue it in frontend before you could use it). As for the content, you say you allow users to load up images in backend. Are you saving them in db as `media` posts? Are you looking for [`[gallery]`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) shortcode?

Comment: No, I'm not saving them in database. But I have an upload button that stores the photo to media library. Well this is what I want to do: Admin-Side:
Create an admin-side settings page.
Provide an interface to add/remove images from plugin settings page.
User must be able to change order of uploaded image. 
Front-end:
Create provision for a shortcode like [myslideshow]
When you add shortcode [myslideshow] to any page, it will be replaced by a slideshow of images uploaded from admin-side.
You can use any jQuery slideshow library/plugin.

Comment: *"I'm not saving them in database"* and *"I have an upload button that stores the photo to media library."* are in **direct contradiction**. If you are doing the second, if the images show up in media library, you **are saving them in database**. `[gallery ids="commaSeparatedIds"]` shortcode (linked above) already provides a gallery markup, out of the box, which you might be able to adapt for your task. Or you could define your own [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) that would output whatever markup you want.

Comment: Okay, well where are the images uploaded in media library stored in the database? And which ids are in the gallery markup?

Comment: WordPress is **your** framework of choice, not mine. If you chose it, you should spend the necessary time to learn how to use it, especially since it provides extensive documentation. I suggest asking questions about UI admin side of WordPress on the [dedicated StackExchange community](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) website.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help!